# Skipping bad rows in file with itemProcessor in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

```
20180627;PM;ABC;0029;BYX;Technology Inc;;DUMMY;OK;33900;34.3;1162770;CT;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; //bad line
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  //bad line
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  //bad line
```

Is there a way I can skip the bad lines with no data in my `MyProcessor`:

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Row, Price> {

    @Override
    public Price process(final Row row) throws Exception {

        if (row == null) {

        }

        //Values for lines in file
        Price scp = new Price();

      //set values

        return scp;
    }

}
```

The values of the `Row` object are nulls. I have seen examples with blank lines, but here I am dealing with colons which is actually the delimiter.

Do I have to check for validity of certain fields and prevent object creation and settings ? Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you add more details about what the string can can really include? And what to consider a `bad line`? I'd use a regular expression for checking of corectness.

Comment: So could you define what is bad line means? If you can define then yes, you can use couple options such as strict properties to false, or using PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper

Comment: The bad lines are ones with no data and series of delimiters. For example line 2, 3, and 4 in my question.  How can I skip processing them? As I want to avoid parsing them to Price objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` to separate valid lines from invalid ones and with a custom `FieldSetMapper` map invalid lines to an object called `InvalidLine` (just an example).
In processing phase use a `CompositeItemProcessor` to pass `InvalidLine` objects through a custom `ItemProcessor` and do what do you prefer.